# Tips needed with plotting a subset of google trends data

Tags: r, plot, google-trends

I'm just new with R-programming and Google Trends, so forgive me for this basic question. I successfully acquired some google trends data from a tutorial like this:

```
library(gtrendsR)
library(methods)
usr <- "<usr>"
psw <- "<psw>"
gconnect(usr, psw) 
lang_trend <- gtrends(c("pga", "nhl", "nba", "nfl"))
plot(lang_trend)
```

I get a nice plot for all 4 terms.
[image]
Now I'd like to know how to just plot the data for just nba for example

Thanks in advance!

Comment: since I think this example might not be reproducible, you should add the plot to the question.

Comment: I just added the plot, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could help get you started. From the documentation of the gtrendsR package: lang_trend is "An object of class ‘gtrends’ which is list with six elements containing the results.
"

```
    library(gtrendsR)
    library(methods)
    usr <- "<usr>"
    psw <- "<pwd>"
    gconnect("<usr>", "<pwd>") 
    lang_trend <- gtrends(c("pga", "nhl", "nba", "nfl"))
    plot(lang_trend$trend[ ,"start"], lang_trend$trend[,"nba."], type = "lines")
```